# How to use ffmpeg.exe to produce a video with exact length for time from image sequence in C#?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, timestamp, aforge

We try to use ffmpeg.exe to make a video from image sequence in C#. However, we can't produce a video which has a predict length for time. For example, we want to produce a video whose length of time is one hour; actually, the length of time is only 47 miniutes.

According our understanding, the function, WriteVideoFrame(Bitmap frame, TimeSpan timestamp) of AForge.Video.FFMPEG, can solve this problem. It is because each input frame is associated with a timestamp.

In ffmpeg.exe, however, we now can only use frame to as input of ffmpeg.exe.

Who can show me how to write the command or parameters to input each image and the associated timestamp, the same to WriteVideoFrame(Bitmap frame, TimeSpan timestamp).

Comment: Can you clarify if you want each image from the sequence to have a custom duration, or just want a custom duration for the whole video?

Comment: Hi @Mulvya, thanks for your reply. We set 10 fps for output video in ffmpeg.exe, and write a timer to control system to input a frame into ffmpeg.exe function for each time interval, 0.1 second. However, the timer can't exactly control system to input frame, and resulted input fps is always unless than 10 frames.

Comment: For example, a resulted video that recording time is one hour, however, the actual length of this resulted video is only 47 minutes, and the resulted video is the condensed data of this one hour. In other words, the last frame of 47th minute for resulted video is the real scene in end of 60th minute. We guess that the problem happens in this inconsistency.

Comment: For the function of AForge.Video.FFMPEG, WriteVideoFrame(Bitmap frame, TimeSpan timestamp), this problem can be solved. We think that this inconsistency is solved by the parameter, timestamp. Aforge can adjust this inconsistency according to the timestamp. Because of that, ffmpeg.exe may have this kind of parameter to solve this inconsistency. Anyway, if you have other solution, please kindly show us. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the command you've tried?

Comment: Hi @Mulvya, Our C# code is as follows.            
            pipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipename, PipeDirection.Out);
            //B. open ffmpeg.xex
            p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"ffmpeg.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s " + width.ToString() + @"x" + height.ToString() + @" -pix_fmt rgb24 -r " + framerate.ToString() + @" -i \\.\pipe\" + pipename + @" -an -b:v " + bitrate + @" -vcodec h264_qsv -preset veryslow " + _filename + ".mp4";
             p.Start();

Comment: pipeStream.WaitForConnection();
            Console.WriteLine("[SSS] pipe wait ok");
         
            pipe_sw = new BinaryWriter(pipeStream);

pipe_sw.Write(rgbValues);

Comment: @gyan looks like both, he wants an exact time for each frame which e would happen to also determine the exact time of the whole file